# How can i create own logging instance for each thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

For example, i have these files with classes that i want to use (only example, maybe not working)

```
# helper_one.py

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('HelperOne')

class HelperOne:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def run(self):
        logger.debug('HelperOne::Run function with data: ' + self.data)
        return True
```

.

```
# controller_one.py

import logging

from helper_one import HelperOne

logger = logging.getLogger('ControllerOne')

class ControllerOne:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def run(self):
        logger.debug('ControllerOne::Run function with data: ' + self.data)

        ho = HelperOne(self.data + '_data')
        return ho.run()
```

And i have a file which creates Threads

```
import logging 

from controller_one import ControllerOne

# this function creates threads (its just an example)
def run_task(task_id, data):
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename=os.path.join('logs', str(task_id) + '.log'),
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format='%(asctime)s\t%(name)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(message)s'
    )

    result = ControllerOne(data)

    logging.debug('run_task: ' + result)
```

If i create logging instance like in my example, all log are written in a single file.
How can I, for every thread, create its own logging instance with logging to its own file ?

Regards, Alex.

Comment: I am not very good in python, but if the logger can only be set up statically (i.e. 1 instance per process) then try having separate sub-processes instead of threads.

Comment: @Kam, yes i can do it, but in my situation it's not possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The logger name (the string passed to the `getLogger` function) can be anything you want. As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects) explain:

> The `name` is potentially a period-separated hierarchical value, like `foo.bar.baz` (though it could also be just plain `foo`, for example). Loggers that are further down in the hierarchical list are children of loggers higher up in the list. For example, given a logger with a name of `foo`, loggers with names of `foo.bar`, `foo.bar.baz`, and `foo.bam` are all descendants of `foo`. The logger name hierarchy is analogous to the Python package hierarchy, and identical to it if you organise your loggers on a per-module basis using the recommended construction `logging.getLogger(__name__)`. That’s because in a module, `__name__` is the module’s name in the Python package namespace.

So, using `__name__` as the name is *recommended*, but not *required*. And in fact you're already explicitly violating it:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('ControllerOne')
```

So, you could just use a separate name per thread, by putting a thread ID or name into the logger name. For example:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('ControllerOne.{}'.format(threading.get_ident())
```

Or, in your case, since you seem to have a unique `task_id` for each thread, you can just use that instead of the thread ID.

Of course this means you have to actually *use* the logger; you can't just call `logging.debug`. And you can't rely on the `basicConfig`; you're going to need to explicitly configure the logger in each thread. Since each thread creates its own independent `ControllerOne` instance, the obvious place to do that is in `ControllerOne.__init__`; in that function, you can call `getLogger` with a logger name that incorporates the thread or task ID, create and set a `FileHandler` that also incorporates the thread or task ID in the name, and store it as `self.logger`. Then, whenever you need to log something, you just do `self.logger.debug(…)`.

If that all sounds like gobbledegook to you because you have no idea what a `FileHandler` is, you probably need to read at least the [basic tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) in the HOWTOs, but the [advanced tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial) and [cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook) are also very useful.